# Как убрать пробел или один символ в конце переменной String?

Tags: java

Есть переменная  к примеру  public String s = "140.25 "; в конце в моем случае создается пробел как убрать чтобы было 140.25.
Или как в конце отнять один символ.

Comment: `s = s.trim();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `trim()`:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String s = "140.25 ";
        s = s.trim();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты работаешь со строками, лучше всего использовать **[StringBuffer](http://www.turbopro.ru/index.php/yazyk-programmirovaniya-java/7692-11-stroki-v-java-klass-stringbuffer)**

```
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("Твоя строка");
```

и в твоём случае **substring**-обрезка по символу

```
strBuffer.substring(strBuffer.length()-1);
```

или **deleteCharAt**-удаление символа

```
strBuffer.deleteCharAt(strBuffer.length()-1);
```